# random gift card using woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

for black friday i want to create a sort of lottery in my ecommerce website created with wordpress and woocommerce, when a user buys a product he will receive a code (gift card) and when he will write the code in the dedicated page he will see if he won or not (product or voucher)
I have searched in several plugins but what I find is gift card or promotional code, I want the user to be able to win or lose by using a random in the generated code

Comment: Are you asking for someone to do this for you? Have you tried anything to solve this yourself? We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any plugins that does this, but you should be able to make one yourself. You can use the thank you page of WooCommerce to display a random code and just create a coupon with that code in your functions file or in the plugin file :)